# Reading JSON in PHP with only the libraries in Wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I want to read JSON data coming in to a server that has just enough PHP installed to run WordPress. I can create new .php files, but I don't have the admin permissions to add any libraries that aren't already there.

What's the easiest way to grab & parse the JSON data out of an http request in this situation?

Comment: You don't have `json_decode`?

Comment: That's half the answer. The half that precedes it turns out to be: $json_data = file_get_contents("php://input");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the pointers, all, but the answer I was looking for was a much simpler one. The necessary two lines of code turned out to be:

```
$json_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json_data = json_decode($json_data, true);
```

Line one: Get the json data hitting the page.
Line two: Parse it into a proper hash.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing this within the context of WordPress, you should use the built-in HTTP helper functions (http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API). They are simpler than curl. Example:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( $url );
if( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
   echo 'Response:<pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

The above will return something like this:

```
Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [date] => Thu, 30 Sep 2010 15:16:36 GMT
            [server] => Apache
            [x-powered-by] => PHP/5.3.3
            [x-server] => 10.90.6.243
            [expires] => Thu, 30 Sep 2010 03:16:36 GMT
            [cache-control] => Array
                (
                    [0] => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
                    [1] => post-check=0, pre-check=0
                )

            [vary] => Accept-Encoding
            [content-length] => 1641
            [connection] => close
            [content-type] => application/php
        )
    [body] => {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [message] => OK
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Then you can use json_decode() to change the json into an array: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2):

With cURL and json_decode, you'd do it like this. If you're running Wordpress, chances are these are available.

```
$session = curl_init('http://domain.com/'); // HTTP URL to the json resource you're requesting
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = json_decode(curl_exec($session));
curl_close($session);
echo $json;
```

Comment: `$json = json_decode(curl_exec($session), true);` is better because it avoids the mixture of objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Default WordPress function available Can you try this

Refer this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_json_file_decode/

```
$data = wp_json_file_decode($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/foldername/filename.json'); 
var_dump($data);
```